# Ember .get('lastObject') Not Working As Expected

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a form that submits to a method on my PlaylistController.  From that form submission, I create a song record and commit it.  What's happening is that the all submissions work fine.  A new record is saved and committed.  I can do a App.Song.find() and see that the contents have been updated.

But the second submission goes awry.  The submission is actually committed as a new record, and when I go to the model I find that it has stored another new value.  However, when I try to use .get('lastObject') on a find(), I get the first submission.  The third submission returns the second, and so on.

Here is my code:

```
 // create song in Song model first
  new_song = App.Song.createRecord({
    name: 'test name',
    artist: 'test username',
    soundcloud: '/tracks/'
  });

  new_song.get('store').commit();

  //can't return the song ID when commiting, so need to manually find it
  // find all songs, return last result
  last_song = App.Song.find().get('lastObject');
  console.log(last_song);
```

And here is a console.log(songs_array.get('last_song')); outputs this:

```
Object {id: "ember914", clientId: 30, type: function, data: Object, record: Class}
Object {id: "ember914", clientId: 30, type: function, data: Object, record: Class…}
Object {id: "ember1200", clientId: 31, type: function, data: Object, record: Class…}
Object {id: "ember1408", clientId: 32, type: function, data: Object, record: Class…}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to find the newly created song directly after creating it.  This will not work because it is added to the `find()` array at a later stage of the [Ember Run Loop](http://alexmatchneer.com/blog/2013/01/12/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-the-ember-run-loop/).

The most obvious solution would be to do:

```
// create song in Song model first
new_song = App.Song.createRecord({
  name: 'test name',
  artist: 'test username',
  soundcloud: '/tracks/'
 });

new_song.get('store').commit();

Em.run.next(function() {
  last_song = App.Song.find().get('lastObject');
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFw66/) that demonstrates it.

One thing to note though, is when you encounter such problems, and feel like Ember is working against you (especially when you start worrying about the Run Loop), it probably means you are doing it wrong.

Now the question would be, why are you trying to find the record this way right after creating it?

If you just want to have the record in a variable, you already have it in `new_song`, just pass that along, and it will later be populated with the id. Keep in mind that once you get `last_song` the way you did, you will have `last_song === new_song`, so what was the point of getting it...

If you need to get the ID immediately after creation (which is a very rare scenario), you can do this:

```
new_song = App.Song.createRecord({
  name: 'test name',
  artist: 'test username',
  soundcloud: '/tracks/'
});

new_song.one('didCreate', function() {
  Em.run.next(function() {
    console.log(new_song.get('id'));
  });
});

new_song.get('store').commit();
```

Notice the `Em.run.next` in the above examplet was the , that's just because of a bug that will be fixed very soon.

Comment: So the reason I want the record right away is so that I can take that and store into a playlist model.  Granted, I've just started getting into deeper subjects like the Run loop and Ember-data, so I wasn't sure how to do that.  

I'll try this a little later today and upvote when I get it working, but this all makes sense and should work.  Thanks Teddy!

Comment: You don't need the Id to add it to another model.  You can do `playlist.get('songs').pushObject(new_song)`, or if `Song` belongs to one `Playlist`: `new_song.set('playlist', playlist)`.  Of course you would need to define the relationships in model definitions.

Comment: Teddy, I love you.  That last comment works bang on and removes a bunch superfluous code.  I ended up using self.get('content').get('songs').pushObject(new_song); (self just being var self = this; within my PlaylistController.